# How to get MD5 hash only (Batch Script)

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a batch script that will check the MD5sum of all files in a folder and i found this script on this site

for /r %%f in (*) do (certutil -hashfile "%%f" MD5) >> output.txt

This one is working but any idea how can i get the hash only, without the other text

[Please see text highlighted on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orxyO.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Please give an example of the current output. Is this bash? Linux?

Comment: Hi, it is Windows >> sample output should be hash only without other text, only the highlited text from this image > https://i.stack.imgur.com/orxyO.png

Comment: `for /R %%f in (*) do (certutil -hashfile "%%f" MD5 | find /V ":") >> output.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the two lines that you don't want to include both contain the string `hash` somewhere in them, you can use `find` to filter those lines out.

```
for /r %%f in (*) do (certutil -hashfile "%%f" MD5 | find /v "hash") >> output.txt
```

`find /v` says "return all lines that do not contain this string."

Comment: There's a simpler way of using `find.exe`, the character set used for the MD5 result is effectively alphanumeric, so if you take a look at the output, the lines requested for omission all contain a matching character. That character is the colon **`:`**, so you would use `find /v ":"`. _(As a side note, although unlikely, I'm not sure that the string of four alphanumeric characters `hash` could never be returned in the MD5 result)_.

Comment: MD5s are hexadecimal characters, so `h` will never appear in the output. I could save 3 characters and just do `find /v "h"` though.

Answer (score 0):

DOS is hard to work with (compared to bash on linux, for example), but I managed to get something like this working locally:

Simple example using just `:` as a deliminator (like in your example, where the MD5 hash is after the `:`):

```
$ @echo hello:me
hello:me
$ for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==:" %a in ('echo hello:me') do @echo %b
me
```

- `tokens=1,2`: fetch tokens 1 & 2 - assign to %a %b respectively
- `delims==:`: tokenize on `:`
- `echo %b`: print token #2

Extrapolate to your case (which I can't reproduce locally, so this is a guess):

```
$ for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==:" %a in ('for /r %%f in (*) do (certutil -hashfile "%%f" MD5)') do @echo %b
```

See if that gets you closer.

Comment: This is the first time I've attempted to do this in DOS, so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: Actually no. This isn't your first time because DOS is not cmd.exe. DOS was an operating system.

Comment: Fair enough. That's true.

Comment: SomethingDark is on to it. I had assumed it was a single line, but wrapped. Mine wont work.